# Set first day of the week using array

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have a string array which holds the names of the weekdays:

```
private final String[] weekdays = new String[]{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
```

I have set Monday as the first day of the week by default.

Now I have given the user the option to select if s/he wants to set either Sunday or Monday as the first day of the week:

```
if (firstDay == 0) {
    holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[position]);
 }
```

Using the same String array how do I set Sunday as the first day of the Week?

```
else {
     holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[position]-1);  //this returns an error 
}
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
public class CalendarWeekAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private final String[] weekdays = new String[]{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
Context mContext;

   private LayoutInflater mInflater;
   public CalendarWeekAdapter(Context c)
   {
          mContext=c;
          mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
   }
   public int getCount()
   {
          return weekdays.length;
   }
   public Object getItem(int position)
   {
          return position;
   }
   public long getItemId(int position)
   {
          return position;
   }
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
          ViewHolder holder=null;
          if(convertView==null)
          {
                 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_week_gridcell, parent,false);
                 holder = new ViewHolder();
                 holder.txtWeekdays=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.weekdays);
                 if(position==0)
                 {                             
                       convertView.setTag(holder);
                 }
          }
          else
          {
                 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
          }

          if (firstDay == 0) {
              holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[position]);
          }
          else {
              holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[position]); 
          }

          return convertView;
   }

}
static class ViewHolder
{        
      TextView txtWeekdays;                 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to subtract 1 from a string. That's not really going to work.

What you need to do is create a method that returns the day of the week. Something like this:

```
public String getDayOfWeek(int day, int firstDay) {
   String[] weekdays;
   if (firstDay == 0)
      weekdays = new String[]{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
   else
      weekdays = new String[]{"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
   return weekdays[day];
}
```

Now, you COULD do this by position (using `weekdays[position - 1]`), but the above will help you avoid errors in your code (indexing -1 for example), and give you more clarity as to what is being returned.

Comment: I knew I could do this i.e create another string array but was just wondering if there was a more efficient way of setting the first day of the week using the same string.

Comment: If that's the case, I would go with @BharatSinha's answer. It will allow you to control the base index (0 or 1) and determine the rest of the week from there. Keep in mind though, the method I've posted is just as efficient, since it still allocates only one array.

Answer (score 2):

What i would do in this case is

```
private final String[] weekdays = new String[]{"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};
```

and

```
if (user selected monday) {
    days_start_index = 1;
    days_end_index = 7;
} else {
    days_start_index = 0;
    days_end_index = 6;
}
```

You can use it in the following manner...

```
for (int i=days_start_index; i<=days_end_index;i++)
    // Do whatever you want
```

**EDIT**
To access `n`th day you should use...

```
weekdays[n-1+days_start_index]
```

**OR**

Else could be tweaked in this manner:

```
if(position==0){
    position = 7;
}
holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[position-1]);
```

Comment: `weekdays[position-1]` would throw an exception if `position == 0`. +1 for the first part of your answer :)

Comment: @BharatSinha, I'm not sure why this doesn't work. It should show the weekdays in the order, but it doesn't budge whether I select Sunday or Monday, it still displays Monday as the first day of the week.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't answer your question directly, this would be best implemented as an enum, something like this:

```
/*
 * Easily Localize these by setting the short and long day
 * names using standard Java localization techniques
 * 
 * */
enum DayOfWeek {
    MONDAY("Mon", "Monday"), 
    TUESDAY("Tue", "Tuesday"),
    WEDNESAY("Wed", "Wednesday"),
    THURSDAY("Thurs", "Thursday"),
    FRIDAY("Fri", "Friday"),
    SATURDAY("Sat", "Saturday"),
    SUNDAY("Sun", "Sunday");


    DayOfWeek(final String shortDayName, final String longDayName) {
         this.shortName = shortDayName;
         this.longName = longDayName;
    }

    public String shortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public String longName() {
        return longName;
    }

    private final String shortName;
    private final String longName;
}
```

The values are then much more easily manipulated and even localized. You can write a method that takes a DayOfWeek and returns the next day and previous day when passed a day etc.

Answer (score 0):

it should be [position -1] instead of **weekdays[position]-1** . and check for the position ==0 ( index error)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but is it something like this you want?

```
else {
     holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[weekdays.length - 1]); 
}
```

If you want the las index:

```
else {
     holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[position - 1]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[position == 0? weekdays.length - 1 : position - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure where your position variable comes from, but in your line of thinking, the following would work:

```
holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[position-1])
```

I would suggest using an Enum to hold the days of the week instead. This would be a bit more readable.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check. This one throws `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsexception`

Comment: I see now, you actually need the whole array, with the days in proper order. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'll suggest to use enum for week days, since it's finite and predefined, plus you won't have ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Secondly, I would create week abstraction, since it depends from context (e.g. usually working week is only 5 days, but in Israel it starts from Sunday), so this abstraction will have starting day, and collection of week days.